# Disjoint edge finder algorithm analysis

Tags: big-o, analysis, graph-algorithm

I have an algorithm to find the set of edge-disjoint paths in an undirected graph.

1. Start with a list of all edges in the graph
2. While there are still available edges in the list, execute depth/breadth first search to find a path.  If a path is found, save it, remove edges from both list and graph and increment path counter
3. Remove first available edge from list and designate it current path
4. Try to match current path to list of saved edges
5. If no avaliable edge matches, path is finished
6. If an available edge can extend the current path, add it to current path and remove from edge list, then continue trying to extend the current path.

I believe that 2 and 3 execute in O(E(V+E) + E) time because

- breadth/depth first search executes in O(V+E) time
- Search executes over E edges in the list
- Removal of E edges from list and graph

The latter part of the algorithm executes in O(E^2) time due to the two loops required to iterate over the edge list.

Therefore, I have a final worst case of  O(E(V+E)+ E^2+E)=O(EV+2E^2+E)

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not right. As far as I understand your problem O(E(V+E)+ E^2+E) is right. But in Big O Notation one would take the "biggest" event for the complexity. You have three complexity classes in it:

1. E(V+E)
2. E^2
3. E

Point 3 is eliminated by point 2, because two is bigger in every case. In "worst case" E is V^2. With that known you can determine that Point 1 is the biggest complexity part (V^3+V^4 > V^4). Your algorithm is right, your assumptions about the parts as well, so the algorithmic complexity of this problem would be: **O(E(V+E))**

You can have a look at these [slides](http://www.informatik.uni-augsburg.de/thi/personen/lei11.pdf) . At slide 23 the complexity is written down and fits your calculations ;)